# moving funds from an IRA to a 401k

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira

I have funds in both an IRA and a company matched 401K.  I am looking to consolidate the accounts.
Are there any penalties to moving my funds from the IRA to the 401K? (different companies) - I am currently very unhappy with the broker/company that the IRA is with.

Comment: I understand that is not the question, but you can for sure move the IRA to another company (leaving it an IRA) without penalties; and probably without cost. They will all be eager to get you as a customer.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that for sure - the receiving company almost assuredly won't charge you (in fact, you might well come out ahead: I know Motif, at least, will pay *you* 150$ to move an IRA from elsewhere to them), but some brokerages will charge you to move an account out. I will say, why would you want to move funds from an IRA to a 401k? I would happily *pay* to get my 401k funds out into an IRA, so I actually had control over it.

Answer (score 2):

There are no penalties, but your 401k plan needs to accept such rollovers. Not all 401k plans accept them, and they're not required to. Check with the 401k custodian or your company's benefits team.

You can always roll over your IRA to a different provider, regardless.

Comment: To add to your answer. Even if the 401k provider allowed it ,which seems unlikely, moving into a 401K from a self-directed IRA will only limit their investment choices and potentially increase their fees. It's not a good idea even if they COULD do it.

Comment: @JohnFx: There are cases when it's a good idea -- e.g. if you want to do a backdoor Roth IRA contribution.